# How to get the Lower quartile and Upper quartile values from a Point in the Tooltip of Highcharts-Box Plot

Tags: highcharts

How do I get a lower quartile and an upper quartile value from a point in a Highcharts Box Plot?

I am able to get the minimum and maximum values by using

`point.low` and `point.high`.

Comment: If some one is looking for this it is


point.q and point.q3 which is what it is reffered in the source of the highchart and it worked for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From reading the [docs](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#plotOptions.boxplot) and looking at the DOM for Highcharts boxplot you can do something like this:

```
plotOptions: {
    series: {
        cursor: 'pointer',
        events: {
            click: function (event) {
                console.log('low:' + event.point.low);
                console.log('q1:' + event.point.q1);
                console.log('median:' + event.point.median);
                console.log('q3:' + event.point.q3);
                console.log('high:' + event.point.high);
            }
        }
    }
},
```

It seems to me that point.q1, point.median, point.q3 are all accessible.